# Render Not Defined - Keyframed text with React and MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get text to scroll one line at a time. What I have is a name, pronouns, and than some very humble sub-text.

The sub text is suppose to scroll one item in at a time and continuously rotate between each of the items.

I've created a seperate component `TitleScroll.jsx` to manage the scrolling that will go in to `Hero.jsx`

I keep getting a `Render Not Defined` error, but am unsure if I should even be using `Render` or if I should be using `Return` instead. Someone able to explain what I am doing wrong, and how I can correct this?

**Hero.jsx**

```
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import TitleScroll from "./TitleScroll";

const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <Grid
      component="section"
      container
      flexDirection="row"
      justifyContent="space-between"
      alignItems="center"
      sx={{
        position: "relative",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        overflow: "hidden",
        zIndex: -100,
        mb: 15,
      }}
    >
      <Box
        padding={50}
        sx={{
          height: "50%",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
        }}
      >
        <Typography
          component="h2"
          color="secondary"
          sx={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 300 }}
        >
          Hi, my name is
        </Typography>
        <Box>
          <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 60, pt: -40 }}>Ainsley</Typography>
          <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 200 }}>(they/them)</Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box component="div" sx={{ height: 50, overflow: "hidden" }}>
          <Box component="div" sx={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <TitleScroll />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Typography component="h2" color="secondary" gutterBottom>
          Hi Im Ainsley!
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

**TitleScroll.jsx**

```
import { keyframes, css } from "@emotion/react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import React from "react";

const TitleScroll = keyframes`
    20% {
        transform: translateY(-50px);
    }

    40% {
        transform: translateY(-100px);
    }

    60% {
        transform: translateY(-150px);
    }

    80% {
        transform: translateY(-200px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-250px);
    }
`;

render(
  <div
    css={css`
      animation: ${titleScrollEffect} 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    `}
  >
    <Typography
      sx={{
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        color: "#a29bfe",
      }}
    >
      Amazing
    </Typography>

    <Typography
      sx={{
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        color: "#a29bfe",
      }}
    >
      Cool
    </Typography>

    <Typography
      sx={{
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        color: "#a29bfe",
      }}
    >
      Rad
    </Typography>

    <Typography
      sx={{
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        color: "#a29bfe",
      }}
    >
      Neat
    </Typography>

    <Typography
      sx={{
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        color: "#a29bfe",
      }}
    >
      Groovy
    </Typography>

    <Typography
      sx={{
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        color: "#a29bfe",
      }}
    >
      Chill
    </Typography>
  </div>
);

export default TitleScroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

Render is a method that tells react to what to render.

Return is just the output of the function

Before react 16 class components using render function to return the required jsx. With the update, you can return jsx directly.

Comment: I should be fine just changing render, to return(...)?

Comment: Yes or change it to class component but that's not recommended :)

Comment: What would be a better way to do that than? Sorry still clearly new to this. Just trying to make sure I don't make the mistake again.

Comment: Well, for usability, I often feel restrained when I use class components but there are times that you may want to use them. First of all, to me, the code is easier to read that way. They are easier to test and potentially have better performance. It feels easier to apply separation of concerns. There are more on the internet if you just google it. Also, mistakes are a thing don't worry about them, you learn better when you make mistakes and overcome them.

Comment: forgot to mention, you are using functional components as I saw, which is recommended

Comment: I went ahead and started with changing it to return(...) and now am gettin a "Return state is not allowed here" I did remove render(..)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242255/discussion-between-ozan-mudul-and-ransomenote).